# HTML character entity references for maximize and minimize

Tags: html, html-entities

Is there anything like `&times;` for maximizing or minimizing?

`&times;` outputs an X. Likewise, is there anything built in available for maximize and minimize?

Comment: No (times comes as part of math symbols). But you can perhaps use up and down arrow symbols as alternatives..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `&minus;` for minimize(−) and  `&plus;` for maximize(+) like `&times;` for ×

Answer (score 14):

Well, for minimize, we have pure `_` or `&#95;` and for maximize `&square;`. If you are expecting a fancy option for minimize, you can also use `&boxminus;`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx53Q/)</kbd>

```
&times; &#95; &square;
```

The above will output × _ □

For more information, you can refer to *[Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)*.

Answer (score 10):

Unicode's Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs provides some window button glyphs:

🗕︎ 🗖︎ 🗙︎
`&#128469;&#xFE0E; &#128470;&#xFE0E; &#128473;&#xFE0E;`

🗕︎ 🗗︎ 🗙︎
`&#128469;&#xFE0E; &#128471;&#xFE0E; &#128473;&#xFE0E;`

However, these will not display well on all platforms. You should use SVG if you can.
(Or, include and use a font that specifically defines these.)

The `&#xFE0E;` is to [prevent display as emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip). It's not guaranteed tho, and for instance my phone doesn't support it and will show emoji for all four of these glyphs.