# font for minimize and maxmize buttons in html

Tags: html, web, frontend

I want to write the code of windows calculator in HTML and I need to use font for minimize and maximize buttons. what should I use? I know the font for close that is `&#10006;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML character entity references for maximize and minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971476/html-character-entity-references-for-maximize-and-minimize)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this website for UTF-8 icons:

https://www.utf8icons.com/

The code for Maximize  is:

```
&#128470;
```

and this is the Restore :

```
&#128471;
```